# Creating a repeat function in TCL

Tags: tcl

Hello all I am very new to the TCL coding and would like some help with my macro:

```
set form {
  GuidoForm leftside {
    -default_buttons
    -label "Spilt of EOM Solid"
    -layout BoxLayout Y_AXIS

    GuidoField Volume {
      -label "<html> <b><font color=\"blue\">Volume:"
      -format none
      -width 6
      -low_bound 0
      -null false
      }
    GuidoField Totalmetres {
      -label "<html> <b><font color=\"blue\">Total Metres:"
      -format none
      -width 6
      -low_bound 0
      -null false
      }
    GuidoField Ore {
      -label "<html> <b><font color=\"blue\">Ore:"
      -format none
      -width 6
      -low_bound 0
      -null false
      }
    GuidoField Waste {
      -label "<html> <b><font color=\"blue\">Waste:"
      -format none
      -width 6
      -low_bound 0
      -null false
      } 
    GuidoField file {
      -label "<html> <b><font color=\"blue\">Give output filename:"
      -format none
      -default "Spilt_1"
      -translate none
      -display_length 20
      -max_length 60
      -null false
      }     
    }
  }
if {"[expr ($Ore + $Waste) == ($Totalmetres)]"} {
  puts "Ore and Waste MATCH Total metres"

} else {puts "Ore and Waste DO NOT MATCH Total metres please review data" 
  proc repeat
}
```

Im trying to make the end result repeat back to the start of the macro is the else portion is not met. Im not to sure how to make the macro jump back to a line or past a line of code. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I don't know what all the "Guido" stuff is. If it's some sort of GUI, you'll need to read about "event driven programming" in Tcl.

Comment: One thing to note: the first argument to `if` is already evaluated using `expr` so you don't need to do it explicitly: `if {($Ore + $Waste) == $Totalmetres} ...` -- assuming those variables exist

Comment: You may also want to use [`tailcall`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/tailcall.htm) and [`info level 0`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/info.htm#M30)

Comment: What do you want the repeat to do? Where do the variables come from? Why would they change on repetition? Do you want a delay between repeats? Do you want to use those variables with those `GuidoField` calls at all? (Do you even want to call them?) So many questions before can feel able to try to answer...